# Proving the divergence of $\sum_2^\infty{\frac{1}{n \log n}}$ using comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof

It is quite straightforward using the Cauchy Condensation test. But is there any way to solve this problem using some well known comparison test?

I cannot think of any way of my own. Any help/hint is appreciated.

Comment: Integral test?  Comparing to the integral $\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\log(x)}dx$.

Comment: @D.B. no, not the integral test. Some other approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$f(x):= \frac{1}{x\log(x)}$$ 
is for $x > 2$ decreasing. Thus we get
$$\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{1}{n \log(n)} \ge \int_{3}^{m} \frac{1}{x \log(x)} \, d x = \log \log m - \log \log (3)$$
The same argument can be used to find an upper bound. This gives the asymptotic formula
$$\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{1}{n \log(n)} \sim \log \log m.$$

Comment: I thought of the integral test too. But I think the problem might either be very trivial or might have some mistakes (homework problem). In addition, there is no hint of the integral test in the chapter.

Comment: I'll accept the effort anyway.